# Finding date in file, getting data after it

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

Help me brainstorm how I would solve this problem.

I have a file of dates with corresponding data, the format looks like this:

```
Date,data,data,data,data,data
Date,data,data,data,data,data
```

It's a plain csv file, only commas being used.

I need to be able to select a beginning date. And then get the data for the next 20 days beginning with the date selected.

Date format:
2007.05.21 (y,m,d)

So I think it would be best to search for the date. Either loading the entire file first into memory or read line by line. The file is only 1 megabyte, however I might want to do this with a 100 megabyte file as well. Is that still little?

Also I will want to do this very many times. I think I may want to keep the file in memory for the entire run of the program. So I can repeatedly access it.

After finding the date. I need to be able to get column 2 day 1, column 4 day 4. Ect. However there is always the same amount of columns for each day. So I guess if this is loaded into some kind of array I can always know in what array number the next and next day starts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also any code examples provided would really help. This is not a homework problem or anything like that and I'm really new to programming.

Comment: Are the lines in the CSV sorted by date?

Comment: @trion Yes they are. However they don't have every day so there are gaps in terms of calendar days. So the only way this helps, is if I want to then search for the next day, I know where to start the search. - to rephrase I'll always want the next 19 lines. But if I'm selecting a new day to search for, then I will know where to start the search if the day is older than the previous.

Comment: @trion - whooops I now get why you asked this question. Yes I want to get the next 19 lines. always. Its that simple. find beginning point in file and get that line + next 19 lines. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No, that's not why I'm asking. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user `csv` library to parse your file like this line by line

```
require 'csv'
date_to_search = Date(2009, 10, 10)
CSV.read('yourfilename.txt', :col_sep => ',') do |row|
  # row will be an array of strings which you can parse
  cur_date = Date.parse(row[0])
  if cur_date == date_to_search
    # you are set to read next 19 lines
    # you can keep a counter and increment it after parsing each line (row here)
  end
  # compare and check if you need this line (and next 19)
  # other calculations
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks handy. Except that it may take me a very long time to figure out what to do next. I understand the require 'csv', csv.read file name and column seperator. But the do |row| and cur_date I have no clue what to do with. As just an example where would I put my selected date for it to search for?

Answer (score 0):

As your data is sorted, [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary%20Search) is what you want to use.

Simply put, you look up an element near the middle of your CSV, compare its date to the one you're looking for, and continue recursively in the matching half of the file (See the Wikipedia link for details).

Binary search has a runtime complexity of O(log n), which means that the number of read operations on a file containing 1,000,000 lines (Reasonable estimation for 100 MB) will never (under normal circumstances, that is, lines of different length are equally distributed) exceed 20.

Therefore, there is no need to keep the file in memory, quite the contrary. The operating system's disk cache will do the task of accelerating consecutive operations for you without running into memory shortage.

To read and process a line, you first need to find its first character, which is either the first letter after a newline character (\n) or the beginning of the file. Reading multiple lines can be achieved similar.
To parse a line, I suggest you split the line at the separation characters and/or the date's dots. This is, of course, only appropriate if the CSV comes from a trustworthy source and never changes its layout.